# Flask redirect from a different class

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to call a function that has a flask redirect which exists in a certain class.
My files are like so:

```
--- Lib/config.py
--- Lib/lib.py
--- auth.py
```

My code inside `lib.py`

```
    import os
    import json
    import time
    import requests
    from Lib.config import APP_UID, REDIRECT_URI
    from flask import redirect


    class PyLi:
        def __init__(self):
            self.app_uid = APP_UID
            self.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

       def code_redirect(self):
        d = {'client_id=' + self.app_uid, 'redirect_uri=' + self.redirect_uri,
            'response_type=' + 'code'}
        return redirect("https://website.com/oauth/authorize?%s" %
            ("&".join(d)))
```

My `config.py` is just used to define the env variables I'm calling.

```
from decouple import config

APP_UID = config('APP_UID', cast=str, default=None)
...
```

And in `auth.py` I am calling it like so:

```
from Lib import lib

@token.route("/authorize", methods=['GET'])
def redirect():
    auth = lib.PyLi()
    auth.code_redirect()
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't returning `auth.code_redirect()`

Comment: @JaredSmith Yup I just noticed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` on the last line of `redirect()` view function. Add it as follows:

```
@token.route("/authorize", methods=['GET'])
def redirect():
    auth = lib.PyLi()
    return auth.code_redirect()
```